Cohomology ring of P(V) is generated by first Chern class of the hyperplane bundle
The following fact is stated in Bott and Tu's Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology on pp. 269:
$$H^*(P(V))\cong\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^n)$$ where $V$ is a complex vector space of dimension $n$, $S:=\{(\ell, v)\in P(V)\mid v\in\ell\}$ is the tautological subbundle, and $x=c_1(S^*)$ is the fist Chern class of $S^*$, the dual of $S$.
The authors say that a short spectral sequence argument proves this isomorphism. However, I am looking for a basically elementary proof of this fact (i.e. without spectral sequence; by hand). I don't really even know where to start here, so any indications or ideas would be quite helpful, though a full computation would also be much appreciated. As indicated in the comments, any approach is welcome. I think many interesting answers are possible.

Are you happy with solutions using standard AT tools, as opposed to differential forms? One certainly doesn't need a spectral sequence to show this, but I have little experience with the setting of Bott & Tu.

I would love to know any solutions using standard AT tools. That said, for the notes that I'm writing, I will probably use the differential forms approach, though I am not married to it!

You can find a cell decomposition of CP^n similar to the one for RP^n (attach the "upper hemisphere") - this only has one cell in each even dimension so the (co)homology is Z in each even dimension. Now, you can use poincare duality to identify the generator x of H^2 with a bump function on the normal bundle on a hyperplane. Taking the intersection of n hyperplanes gives a point, which is PD to the generator of H^2n. Hence, H^2k must be generated by x^k.

Note that the cohomology ring of $P(V)$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{R}$ can be computed by a rather elementary argument using the Mayer–Vietoris sequence (to compute the groups) and Poincaré duality (to compute the ring structure). Thus, it would remain to show $x = c_1(S)$ is a generator of $H^2(P(V))$.
Here is an independent argument from Milnor–Stasheff that does not rely on first computing the cohomology ring of $P(V)$. It uses only the Gysin sequence, which can be found in Chapter 14 of Bott & Tu. By the definition in Bott & Tu, $x = c_1(S)$ is equal to the Euler class of $S$. Let
$$
E = \{(\ell, v) \in P(V) \times S^{2n - 1} \mid v \in \ell\}
$$
be the unit circle bundle of $S$. Note that the projection onto the second coordinate gives a diffeomorphism $E \cong S^{2n - 1}$. Then the Gysin sequence for the circle bundle $E$ reads
$$
0 = H^{i + 1}(E) \xrightarrow{\pi_*} H^{i}(P(V)) \xrightarrow{\wedge x} H^{i + 2}(P(V)) \xrightarrow{\pi^*} H^{i + 2}(E) = 0
$$
for all $0 \leq i \leq 2k - 2$. Hence, for $1 \leq i \leq n$, the group $H^{2i}(P(V))$ is isomorphic to $H^0(P(V)) = \mathbb{R}$ and is generated by $x^i$. This completes the proof.

Thank you for the answer Frank, this is very helpful. Could you say a bit more about how Poincaré duality obtains the ring structure? I see the Mayer-Vietoris argument, though I don't yet see how to use duality to get the ring structure or how to get $c_1(S)$ involved (though maybe I'm missing something obvious in the last bit).

Sorry I forgot to use the @Frank feature

@Dowdow The key fact is that Poincaré duality implies that the wedge product is nondegenerate as a map $H^k(M) \otimes H^{n - k}(M) \to H^n(M) = \mathbb{R}$. You need to use induction on the dimension of $V$ and this fact to compute the cohomology ring. A separate argument is needed to show that $c_1(S)$ is a generator of the cohomology ring.

I see the argument now, thank you
